# Spring MVC Validate form and return data if has errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-form

I can successfully validate my form and even return the errors. 
My problems started when my view had a few selects that needed to be populated with the data coming from the controller.

When i do model.addAttribute(...) it stops passing the errors to the view:

```
 public String registerSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("jconcorrente") Jconcorrentes concorrente, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){

         if(result.hasErrors()) {
             model.addAttribute("listJdistrito", this.jdistritoService.listJdistrito());
             model.addAttribute("listJtipocodiden", this.jtipodocidenService.listJtipodociden());
             model.addAttribute("jconcorrente", new Jconcorrentes());
                return "register";
            }
```

So my question is how can i pass the data without affecting the validation errors?

Comment: Try to remove `model.addAttribute("jconcorrente", new Jconcorrentes()); ` from your if.

Comment: If i do that it passes the errors but my selects don't get populated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your errors aren't getting populated because you are adding new instance of your model attribute directly into the model.

Try to remove this line:

```
model.addAttribute("jconcorrente", new Jconcorrentes());
```

from your if statement and create new method like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("jconcorrente")
public Jconcorrentes getJconcorrentes() {
    return new Jconcorrentes();
}
```

Leave everything else the same and it should work.

Comment: Thank you that solved it. But i'm guessing this will always add an ModelAttribute("jconcorrente") for each method i have defined in my controller. Right? Is it possible to do this conditionally (only in the required methods)?

Comment: No it won't add it in each method, you also have to sepcify `ModelAttribute("jconcorrente")` in the method.